# What is the best way to implement form fields changes acceptance process

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, activiti

I have a form on which there are a lot of fields defined like firstName, lastName etc.
Additionaly this form can be in a different states of the business process like new, active or rejected.
If form is in active state then some field changes require acceptance of other user so for example if I change firstName value then form should process from active state to the waiting_for_acceptance state. I have implemented it using process library and my own java code however I'm wondering can it be done in simpler way with Activiti/jBPM and Drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on several factors.

- The number of fact types (= fields in your form).
- The complexity of the rules for updating the values
- The envisaged flexibility over time of these rules
- The necessity of keeping these rules independent from the application

If you are happy with the current implementation, there's no reason to change it.